# how to get monthly and yearly totals using dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm kind of new to the power bi. I want to calculate the monthly yearly totals from the column Amount and TRD_date column. Please see the below data 
[image: Data of the table]

Comment: If I am not wrong, you want to show this in a Power BI report, why don't you simply use the date in a filter (any) and use the Amount (sum) in a card to display.

Still if you want to achieve this is DAX, you will have to  create a filter using below formula:
Measure = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Amount]);Month('Table'[TRD_Date])==1)

Comment: Create a dedicated Date table first with MonthName and MonthNumber (for ordering) etc. Then you can drop Year and Month onto a Matrix and it'll aggregate your data automatically for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution does not require DAX.  You can do this easily in Power Bi Report Desktop.  Just follow these steps:

Step 1- create a new Report and on a blank report, click the Table visual (show highlighted in yellow below)

[image]

Step 2- Bring in your datasource and drag over to the Values area of the visual, the Date column first, then the Amount column second.  Your values will look like:

[image]

Step 3- Remove (click the X) for the Date-> Quarter Value and Date-> Day value.  This will total the amounts for you by Month and Year.

Your table will be a shown below:

[image]

My data is shown here for reference:

[image]